# Why does using mouseover create a laggy experience? JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
  
   
            var mouseX;
   var mouseY;
   $(document).mousemove( function(e) {
       mouseX = e.pageX; 
       mouseY = e.pageY;
   });
   $(".test").mouseover(function(){
      $('#DivToShow').css({'top':mouseY,'left':mouseX, 'display':'block', 'z-index':'10'});
   });
   $("#DivToShow").mouseover(function(){
      $('#DivToShow').css({'top':mouseY,'left':mouseX, 'display':'block', 'z-index':'10'});
   });
   $(".test").mouseleave(function(){
      $('#DivToShow').css({'top':mouseY,'left':mouseX, 'display':'none', 'z-index':'10'});
   });
```

```css
body {
font: 1em/1.67 'Open Sans', Arial, Sans-serif;
margin: 0;
background: #010101;
}

.masonry {
margin: 10em 10em;
padding: 0;
-moz-column-gap: 4.3em;
-webkit-column-gap: 4.3em;
column-gap: 4.3em;
font-size: .85em;
}

.item {
display: inline-block;
background: #3D3D3D;
color: white;
padding: 1em;
margin: 0 0 1.5em;
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid #737373;
border-radius: 5px;
text-align: center;
}

.item:hover {
-webkit-filter: contrast(.2);
filter: contrast(.2);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {
.masonry {
-moz-column-count: 2;
-webkit-column-count: 2;
column-count: 2;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
.masonry {
-moz-column-count: 3;
-webkit-column-count: 3;
column-count: 3;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
.masonry {
-moz-column-count: 4;
-webkit-column-count: 4;
column-count: 4;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1100px) {
.masonry {
-moz-column-count: 5;
-webkit-column-count: 5;
column-count: 5;
}
}

.item .img_1 {
display: block;
height: 130px;
width: 275px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://www.sethjfreeman.com/Resources/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<div id="DivToShow" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: green; display: none; position: absolute;"></div>
  <div class="masonry">
     <a href="/ProjectHolder/WebProjects/GoogleReplica/index.php"><div class="item test"><img src="http://www.sethjfreeman.com/HomePage/ItemImages/GoogleReplica.png" class="img_1">Google.com Replica</div></a>
      <a href="/ProjectHolder/WebProjects/PhPToMySQLStoringFormInformation/index.php"><div class="item">Php Form <br> MySQL Database</div></a>
      <a href=""><div class="item">...</div></a>
      <a href=""><div class="item">...</div></a>
      <a href=""><div class="item">...</div></a>
      <a href=""><div class="item">...</div></a>
      <a href=""><div class="item">...</div></a>
      <a href=""><div class="item">...</div></a>
      <a href=""><div class="item">...</div></a>
      <a href=""><div class="item">...</div></a>
      <a href=""><div class="item">...</div></a>
      <a href=""><div class="item">...</div></a>
      <a href=""><div class="item">...</div></a>
      <a href=""><div class="item">...</div></a>
      <a href=""><div class="item">...</div></a>
      <a href=""><div class="item">...</div></a>
      <a href=""><div class="item">...</div></a>
      <a href=""><div class="item">...</div></a>
      <a href=""><div class="item">...</div></a>
  </div>
```

*Using Full Page Will Work Better.*

**Description:**
When hovering over the div with the class (test) it will display the div with the id (DivToShow) and continue to move the div around with the mouse. But it jumps when it moves. Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [mouseover](https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) event you are using here is only triggered when the pointer enters the element. You'll want to use the [mousemove](https://api.jquery.com/mousemove/) event, which is triggered when the pointer moves within an element.